# GNUPLOT: changing the size of the canvas

Tags: gnuplot

I am using terminal aqua. I use splot and set view equal xyz so that I get the same scaling on all axes. However the resulting plot is very small and only uses less than half the available drawing space. How can I scale up the plot up so it ocupies the whole space?

Answer (score 1):

You can scale the plot using the `scale` value for `set view`. The syntax is

```
set view <rot_x>{,{<rot_z>}{,{<scale>}{,<scale_z>}}}
```

In order to only scale the plot, without changing the view angles, you can leave the first values empty:

```
set view equal xyz
set view ,,1.5
splot sin(x)*cos(y)
```